# Using const with a pointer in c

Tags: c, pointers, constants

I don't understand why the following code works

```
typedef struct {
double x;
double y;
double z;
} abc;

static void test(abc const* b)
{
    (void)memset((void *)&(b->x), 0, sizeof(double));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    abc blah = {11, 12, 23};

    printf("\n%f - %f - %f\n", blah.x, blah.y, blah.z);
    test(&blah);
    printf("\n%f - %f - %f\n", blah.x, blah.y, blah.z);
    while (1);
}
```

In the function test, I have set b as a pointer pointing to a const value. And yet I'm able to change the value of x.

Comment: C gives you the power to shoot yourself in the foot. Don't be surprised when that happens.

Comment: Don't cast pointers to/from `void *`. Enable compiler warnings and read them.

Comment: I'm stunned how many high rep users don't understand const in C. Sad...

Comment: You should all read this: http://yarchive.net/comp/const.html

Comment: @this: noting that a lot of "high rep users" seem to be contradicting you, you're a bit on a high horse, aren't you?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Read the link.

Comment: @this: Instead of launching into personal attacks, why don't you write an answer of your own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a cast to hack away the `const`-context of the pointer passed into `test`, so your operation is permitted at compilation.

`blah.x` is in fact mutable, so there's nothing undefined about this. It's just really poor style.

Your program's behaviour would be undefined if the object itself were `const`:

> `[C99: 6.7.3/5]:` If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type, the behavior is undefined. If an attempt is made to refer to an object defined with a volatile-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-volatile-qualified type, the behavior is undefined.

However, creating a `const`-qualified handle to that object doesn't make the object `const`; it only means you are prevented (at compile-time) from mutating it through that handle, unless you hack away the `const`ness as you have done here.

Comment: Yup, I agree with this analysis. Plus one.

Comment: The part of the answer that is important here, I guess, is the *const **context*** of `b.x`. I really don't see why a compiler would think it would need to re-load `blah.x` from mem to reg in main after executing `test`. If you could specify why that's not UB, that'd be great.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: It's not UB because it's not UB. Modifying something that may be modified is permitted.

Comment: well, I must admit I'm assuming that modifying members of a `const` struct is modifying that struct. So my question still stands.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: It's not a `const` struct.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: No, it's a pointer-to-`const`, and the point is that that is irrelevant.

Comment: (There is no text to quote - it must be deduced from lack of an exception to other rules.)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Could you please expand on this 'Your program's behaviour would be undefined if the object itself were const' or perhaps provide an example. Many thanks.

Comment: @JJT: For such an example, just make it `const abc blah` in `main`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `(void*)` cast is casting away the `const`-ness of `b`; `memset` is able to modify the memory at that location.

That is well-defined since `b` ultimately points to memory that is **not** `const`.

Comment: Still think I'm correct. *Certainly* correct in C++.

Comment: It's not even the const'ness of b; there's no constness to accessing memory by any address.

Comment: @Olaf No it doesn't. The original object abc was not defined with const. Taking a const pointer to that object will not magically make it retroactively defined with const.

Comment: @this: With regard to the function, it **is** `const`. If the programmer breaks this contract, he must be prepared for nasal demons. Just consider the implementation making the memory area of the object read-only.

Comment: To me this is little more than a broadly equivalent `const_cast` in C++. This has the exact rules as those that I state in the answer. To settle this, we really need a standard ref.

Comment: @LightnessRacesInOrbit has the standard ref: [C99: 6.7.3/5]

Comment: @user694733: No it can't.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: No it's not.

Answer (score 0):

You're explicitly taking the address of a struct member that you got via a `const` pointer; there's nothing stopping you from modifying data at any address in your process' memory here; the mere fact that you consider the struct to be constant doesn't mean you can't mess with the memory containing that struct.

Comment: It is not enforced by the compiler. But you shall not. If you do, you invoke undefined behaviour.

Comment: Agreeing on the *thou shalt not*. Also stressing that if you cast an address to a `void*` the sky is the limit for things you can feck up.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you made `*b` as constant. That does not stop you from going ahead, take an address of a member variable of that structure, casting it to `void *` (and taking away the `const`ness) and modify the value pointed by that pointer.

Comment: C does not provide constants. `const` is a guarantee by the programmer not to change the object.

Comment: @Olaf Right, that's what I tried to mean by _does not stop you_. How do I modify the answer to be proper?

Answer (score -1):

This should be undefined behavior, and it **happend** to work.

[N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) 6.7.3 Type qualifiers

> If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through use
>   of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Not really. He's not modifying the const object, but he's taking the **address** of a member of that object, and modifies it. Nothing in this world prohibits C from allowing this.

Comment: You are right. The DV was unrectified. It is relevant how the object was declared inside the function, as **that** is the scope. `*b` is a `const` object, so 6.7.3 applies.

Comment: The object that was modified was not defined with const in the first place. @MarcusMüller

Comment: @this: Irrelevant. As of the view of the function, the programmer has to keep the `const`-contract. The function cannot (and should not) know where the object is located. The environment might even make the area read-only on function entry.

Comment: @this what Olaf said. For example, with a const object, the compiler might even decide that an expression is compile time known and optimize it away completely, based on the assumption that `test` actually doesn't modify `b`.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: A compiler _cannot_ make that optimisation without knowing so much about the original object that it would already know whether it were originally defined `const` or not.

Answer (score -6):

`const` is just syntactic sugar for the compiler. There's nothing different about the memory slot where your constant is stored v.s. the memory slot where a normal variable is stored. It's all just memory, and it's all read/write memory.

Marking something as const just causes the compiler to forbid EXPLICIT attempts at modifying the value of the constant. e.g. (pseudo-code)

```
const x = 42;
x = 43; // compiler error
```

But doing

```
const int x = 42;
*int y = &x;
*y = 43; // works
```

because the compiler is NOT going to check every single pointer/memory access to see if it's trying to scribble on a "constant" memory block. Performance would be insanely bad, because every single memory access would require a bunch of extra code/scanning to check for "forbidden" operations.

Comment: *"There's nothing different about the memory slot where your constant is stored v.s. the memory slot where a normal variable is stored. It's all just memory, and it's all read/write memory."* This depends on target device, variable placed on flash memory is usually **not** writable.

Comment: The second example is undefined behavior because the object was *defined* with const. *6.7.3, p6: If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type, the behavior is undefined.* Also const is different that constant!

Comment: *"There's nothing different about the memory slot where your constant is stored v.s. the memory slot where a normal variable is stored."*
simply not true; non-const objects handed around are actually bound to be individual objects, whereas there's no real guarantee a const object does even exist on its own -- it might even just be an alias of another identical const object, for all that `test` knows.

Comment: On embedded systems `const` objects are stored in Flash, which is **read-only**. On regular OS with MMU, they are typically also read-only. And no, in C `const` is a contract by the **programmer**. It is not enforced by the compiler, but breaking the contract invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: This is total nonsense, Marc. Compilers _can_ and _will_ compile code for access to `const` objects quite differently (which is why the standard formally declares mutating a `const` object to have undefined behaviour). Have you never inspected a program with a debugger?! However, this is irrelevant to the question, since the question's object is not `const`.